# After changing the screen orientation the fragment is duplicated

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity that creates a fragment programmatically.
the fragment has another fragment inside it.

activity contains fragment A.
fragment A contains fragment B.

everything works perfectly,
except in case I change the orientation of the screen.

when the screen orientation is changed, the fragment is duplicated.

I looked for solutions to my problem on the web (here too),
I covered the official android documentation,
I tried to do my tests:
but I have not come back to find a solution!

I saw other people who have solved by putting the code to create the fragment in this if:

if (savedInstanceState == null) {

}

but it does not work for me!

if I put the code to create the fragment inside that one, no fragment is created.

I tried to segure the life cycle of the activity with the debugging.

when the activity is created for the first time the app passes here:

- activity
- fragment, onattach
- fragment, oncreate
- fragment, oncreateview

when I turn the screen horizontally, the app passes here:

- fragment, onattach
- fragment, oncreate
- activity
- fragment, oncreateview
- fragment, onattach
- fragment, oncreate
- fragment, oncreateview

activity:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ScrollView sv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
            sv = findViewById(R.id.sv);


            LinearLayout ll_fragment = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll_fragment.setId(100);
            ll_fragment.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams LLParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            ll_fragment.setLayoutParams(LLParams);

            ll.addView(ll_fragment);


            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


            ArrayList<Integer> AL_Int = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            AL_Int.add(sv.getId());
            fragment = FragmentA.newInstance(AL_Int);
            fragmentTransaction.add(ll_fragment.getId(), fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
```

fragment:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    public static FragmentA newInstance(ArrayList<Integer> AL_Int_sv_ID) {


        FragmentA f = new FragmentA();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        if(AL_Int_sv_ID.get(0) != null){
            b.putInt("int_sv_ID", AL_Int_sv_ID.get(0));
            b.putBoolean("bool_sv", true);
        }else{
            b.putInt("int_sv_ID", -1);
            b.putBoolean("bool_sv", false);
        }

        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;


    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {

            int int_ScrollView_ID = args.getInt("int_sv_ID");
            boolean bool_ScrollView = args.getBoolean("bool_sv");

            bool_sv = bool_ScrollView;
            int_sv_ID = int_ScrollView_ID;

            if(bool_sv){
                sv = getActivity().findViewById(int_ScrollView_ID);
                sv = FA.findViewById(int_ScrollView_ID);
            }

        }


    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LLParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        ll.setLayoutParams(LLParams);
        ll.setId(20);


        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();

        transaction.add(20, fragmentB);
        transaction.commit();


        return ll;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try again the if (savedInstanceState == null) method. It is the correct way to handle it, you might be doing something wrong, only wrap this 3 lines in the if:

```
fragment = AutoCompleteTextView_Fragment.newInstance(AL_Int); 
fragmentTransaction.add(ll_fragment.getId(), fragment); 
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: fragment A is duplicated. but since fragment B inside fragment A, fragment B is also duplicated.

Comment: You need to try again the if (savedInstanceState == null) method. It is the correct way to handle it, you might be doing something wrong, only wrap this 3 lines in the if:
```fragment = AutoCompleteTextView_Fragment.newInstance(AL_Int);
            fragmentTransaction.add(ll_fragment.getId(), fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();```

Comment: ok, now it works.
thank you.
it did not work because inside of if (savedInstanceState == null) I also put the linear layout.
since I'm there, I wanted to ask you something else.
the following code:

getActivity (). findViewById (int_ScrollView_ID);

it works if I put it in to the oncreateview.
but it does not work if I put it oncreate.
inside all'oncreate back null.

but in theory, even from android documentation, the fragment is assigned to the activity in the onattack.

Comment: I think it would be better to report the solution in your main comment.

Answer (score 0):

had this same problem, try fragmentTransaction.replace() instead of
fragmentTransaction.add()